# Why doesn't the frequency of a cyclotron make an impact on the radius of the path of a charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, velocity, frequency

The cyclotron frequency is given by $$f=\frac{qB}{2πm}$$
Obviously this equation has nothing to do with the radius.

But my question is, when the frequency increases, shouldn't the velocity increase, and thereby increase the radius as the equation for radius is
$$r=\frac{mv}{qB}$$

Comment: pls make you equations into equations. rn they're just each a lone term.

Comment: i hope its okay now

Comment: In a given B field a charged particle of one energy will exhibit circular motion at one radius. At a slightly higher energy the radius expands linearly with energy, and the frequency remains the same. A brilliant insight by Lawrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, the cyclotron frequency **does not** depend on the velocity. So an increase in perpendicular velocity does not translate into an increase in the cyclotron frequency, as you suggest. Instead, it is the gyroradius that increases. This is actually fairly intuitive. The   particle has increased in speed, and therefore in the same amount of time (cyclotron time) it can cover a greater distance (gyroradius). The overall velocity ($v_{||} = \omega_{c}r_{g}$) increases, but the cyclotron frequency remains constant. This is for exactly the same reason that pulling a mass on a spring further back before letting go (thus increasing its initial velocity) will not result in faster oscillation, but will travel a greater distance during each oscillation. In that case, the frequency depends only the spring constant and the mass. Similarly, the cyclotron frequency in a uniform magnetic field depends only on the charge-to-mass ratio of that particle.